# Passing strings between activities, intents not working

Tags: android, android-intent

I am currently working on a project with a friend, where we have a website hosting login details and such. when a user logs in it returns a token to the app, to use as verification for further api calls by the user. (ie. getting the profile). i need to pass this token across other activities (it is a string), and i tried to use intents, but every time i try it comes up with a `nullPointerException` , where the class i'm calling the intent from can't find the extra i'm sending. i've tried putting the code for creating the intent at the top of the `onCreate` method, however this returns `401 errors` from the server as (i assume) the token has no value because it hasn't been sent by the server using the JSONObject request yet. 
here is the code for the main activity (all links removed)(i also didnt include all the imports and variable declarations as i figured they're un-necessary)

```
    String Name,Pass,tokenString;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    token = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV1);
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          Name = name.getText().toString();
            Pass = pass.getText().toString();



            if(Name.equals("") || Pass.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Fields cannot be left empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {

                        JSONObject jsonObject =  new JSONObject(response);
                        setToken(jsonObject.getString("token"));

                        launchHomeActivity();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if(error.networkResponse.statusCode==401) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Incorrect login details, please retry", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }){
                protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("key", "****");
                    params.put("email", Name);
                    params.put("password", Pass);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            MySingleton.getInstance(MainActivity.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
            name.setText("");
            pass.setText("");

        }

    });
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            launchRegisterActivity();
        }
    });

}
private void launchRegisterActivity() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
private void launchHomeActivity() {


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private void setToken(String token){
    tokenString = token;

}
public String getToken(){
    return tokenString;
}

public void createIntent(){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    i.putExtra("Token", getToken());
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```

here is the code for the home activity (the relevant bits) :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    token = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV1) ;
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_Txt);



    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

   final String tokenString = extras.getString("Token");





            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, ProfileUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        // JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        JSONObject jsonObject =  new JSONObject(response);
                         title.setText("Welcome back " +  jsonObject.getString("token") + "!");


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }){
                protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("key", "****");
                    params.put("Token", tokenString);
                    return params;
                }
            };
            MySingleton.getInstance(Home.this).addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);


        }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
(p.s i'm very new to android studio, and learning as i go)

Comment: Hi Jamie, please put your token as an extra in the intent object of launchHomeActivity() rather than createIntent().

Comment: for passing values please use Shared Preferances, you can use that TOKEN anywhere in you application.

Comment: check if Bundle is notNull, so that your app will no crash,

 Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            String tokenString = bundle.getString("Token");
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling  `launchHomeActivity()` after getting Response on `OnResponse()` and `accessToken`. But you stored the `token`  on `createIntent()` which is never called. So call `createIntent()` on `OnResponse()` method after getting `token`.

And this is not best practice to pass token from `Activity` to `Activity`. Better would be store the `token` on `SharedPrefrence` and access it from anywherer . Make a singleton `SharedPreference` class and you can use it on whole application.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, i have added this, and it succeeds in passing the variable however it still returns a 401, meaning that the string passed to the site as token is incorrect, any ideas why this would be wrong?

Comment: Where you are adding your tokren on `Request`??  share your code.

Comment: i have added the code in the edit for the home class

Comment: Still you are using ` launchHomeActivity()` with no token. Seems your request is ok but problem with your token, its still null or incorrect it hink.

Comment: i removed the launchHomeActivity, i only updated the home class

Comment: ive made it print to console the token from home, so it is passing it correctly, i dont understand why the 401 now because it is passing correctly

Answer (score 3):

After getting response from server , you are calling launchHomeActivity method only. But you setting data in "createIntent" method only. i think that is the issue. I have edited the launchHomeActivity method.

```
    private void launchHomeActivity() {


     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    intent .putExtra("Token", getToken());
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment, i have added this, and it is no longer giving a null pointer error, however the server is still returning a 401 meaning the token it is recieving is incorrect, how would i fix that? is the setToken not working?

Comment: you mean the token value  which u are getting from jsonObject ?

Comment: yeah , the token it is sending is receiving a 401

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding bundle (extras) when calling the activity
For example

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
intent.putExtra("Token", "XXX-YYY-ZZZ");  //Imp
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like this..

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
token = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV1) ;
title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_Txt);



String extras = getIntent().getStringExtra("Token);
```

But I will suggest you to better save that token in shared preferences and use if it all your activity.

For Example:

For Setting values in Preference:

```
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 
 MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putString("Token", getToken);
 editor.apply();
```

For Retrieve data from preference:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS_NAME, 
 MODE_PRIVATE); 
 String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
 if (restoredText != null) {
 String name = prefs.getString("Token", "No name defined");//"No name 
 defined" 
 is the default value.

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different intents to call the same activity.class file.
Insted of using two different use only 1 intent,and put data to that Intent only.
NO REQUIREMENT OF TWO DIFFERENT INTENT TO CALL HOME.CLASS ACTIVITY.

```
private void launchHomeActivity() {
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
startActivity(intent);}

public void createIntent(){
Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
i.putExtra("Token", getToken());
startActivity(i);}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Home.class);
i.putExtra("Token", getToken());
startActivity(i)

and on your Home activity get data like below code.

 Intent intent=getIntent();
 String token=intent.getStringExtra("token");
```